# Executing Intern.js script with combination Sikuli / Selenium

Tags: sikuli, intern

I have a scenario where there is need of both Intern.js and Sikuli simultaneously.Intern.js for web application and in between tests,I want to switch to Rich client application for which I am going to use Sikuli.
Is there any way i can use both Sikuli and Intern.js, how i can switch between them.

can i use Intern.js for testing of Rich client application?

Answer (score 0):

Intern uses Selenium, or any other driver implementing WebDriver or the JsonWireProtocol, to test websites in browsers. Whether Intern can test rich clients (or anything else) is determined by whether a driver is available that will let Intern control the target environment. Selenium itself only works with web applications, but there are drivers that provide WD or JWP interfaces to other environments. For example, there is at least one driver for testing Windows desktop applications that implements the JsonWireProtocol : [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver).

I haven't heard of Sikuli ([SikuliX](http://sikulix.com)?) before, but since it doesn't implement WD or JWP and isn't a loadable JS module, there's no *direct* way for Intern to interface with it. However, since you can script Sikuli, you could write Intern tests that would run Sikuli test sessions via the command line (or, presumably, you could write Sikuli tests that would run Intern).